# Howto use a look-behind with a repeated capturing group

Tags: json, regex, python-3.6

Regex for bowling scores

I have been playing about with regex to match the various bowling scores possible (see Bowling Game https://cyber-dojo.org).

I originally wrote the program in Python 3 without the use of regex but now I want a JSON regex version to show how much simpler and clearer it can be (once you understand regex :)

Below explains the problem but the difficulty I am having is with the regex, grouping the 10 frames with scores separately so as to match the bonus.

I need to look in the 10th frame to correctly match what comes in the bonus area.

Also, if you could point out any other mistakes I would be very grateful.

## The Problem

```
Symbols

X     : Strike
/     : Spare
-     : Miss
[0-9] : digit

|     : frame
```

- A score is made up of 1 or 2 symbols separated by a frame symbol.
- There are 10 frames.
- After the 10 frames are the bonus balls scores separated by two frame symbols.

### Example score pattern:

```
8/|X|-/|-4|3-|--|9/|55|23|X||-/
```

- The score pattern is represented as a string.
- Each score consists of 1 Strike or 2 other symbols (not incl. frame).
- A score cannot begin with a Spare.

### Bonus score example (showing preceding 10th frame):

```
    |7-||        # (no bonus ball
    |23||        # (no bonus ball)
    |-/||2       # (1 bonus ball as Spare last in 10th frame)
    |X||X-       # (2 bonus balls as Strike in 10th frame)
    |X||-/       # (2 bonus balls as Strike in 10th frame)
    |X||7/       # (2 bonus balls as Strike in 10th frame)
    |X||XX       # (2 bonus balls as Strike in 10th frame)
```

- The bonus area can be populated by

  - 1 symbol (if the 10th frame score ended with a Spare)
  - or 2 symbols (if the 10th frame score was a Strike)
  - or 0 symbols (if the 10th frame score was neither).
- A bonus score cannot begin with a Spare.
- A Spare cannot follow a Strike.

I have created the following pattern (using https://regex101.com where you can see the breakdown):

```
^(([X\d\-]((?<!X)[\/\-\d]|(?<=X)))\|){10}\|
```

This matched up to the symbols denoting the bonus area.
I would like to use look-behind to determine the score in the 10th frame to determine what occurs in the bonus area.

**Edit**

What I get is the following hint:

"A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data"

However, I cannot get this to work. Being able to do this will allow me to access the scores in all frames, esp. the 10th frame that denotes the bonus area.

## Extra

Is there a way to calculate the scores using JSON, i.e. if we broke the regex pattern down into their sub-parts and assigned a value to that sub-part in JSON?

That way for each matched group we could somehow derive its value so as to calculate the total for the entire match?

Comment: In your example pattern `8/|X|-/|-4|3-|--|9/|55|23|X||-/` there is a double pipe `||` near the end. Does the double pipe only occur before the bonus?

Comment: Yes, these are the two frames symbols marking the bonus area. In this case frame 10 was a strike so two bonus balls. The first was a miss and the second a spare.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think that a regular expression is the best way to solve this problem. If you're looking for the last group only, I would recommend something like this:

```py
# assume str is the score string
split_str = str.split('||')[-1]
```

which is much more readable than any regular expression. If there are other ways to split it if you want every score grouping, for example with this simple regex:

```py
re.split('\|{1,2}', str)
```

which will give you an array of all the scores.

Now, if you do really want to solve this with regex, I don't think there's a reason to use a lookbehind for this. I was able to get the bonus group by adding `(X|[\d\-\/]{1,2})` to the end of your regex. You can play around with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/dJe0GL/1).

As for your bonus question, you can't add up the scores using JSON. [JSON is a way of storing or transmitting data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON). However, you could easily store any information you get from the score strings in a JSON format.

However, adding up those score strings is going to require some conversion of symbols (e.g. X -> 10), and you could store those conversions in JSON. That will look a lot like a Python dictionary:

```
{
    "X": 10,
    "-": 0,
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am interested in all scores not just the bonus. The bonus score is governed by the last score, the 10th frame, and this can be anything that conforms to the rules.

It is not just a matter of splitting on the frames, but ensuring the scores are of the correct format to make my code simpler.

I want to use regexp so as to make validation of the pattern simpler. Rather than using pure code to validate, use regexp with a bit of code.

Your answer to my Extra question is what I was alluding to. Thank you for confirming.